# Libs for HTML sanitizing

Tags: java, html, parsing

I'm looking for a html sanitizer which I can call per API to sanitise strings which I get from my webapp. Are there some useful easy to use libs available? Does anyone knows maybe one or two?

I don't need something big it just must be able to find unclosed tags and close them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) may help you.

Comment: Yes idd, jTidy help me out here. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 25):

https://github.com/OWASP/java-html-sanitizer is now marked ready for production use.

> A fast and easy to configure HTML Sanitizer written in Java which lets you include HTML authored by third-parties in your web application while protecting against XSS.

You can use [prepackaged policies](https://rawgit.com/OWASP/java-html-sanitizer/master/distrib/javadoc/org/owasp/html/Sanitizers.html)

```
Sanitizers.FORMATTING.and(Sanitizers.LINKS)
```

or the [tests](https://github.com/OWASP/java-html-sanitizer/blob/master/src/test/java/org/owasp/html/HtmlPolicyBuilderTest.java) show how you can configure your own easily:

```
new HtmlPolicyBuilder()
    .allowElements("a")
    .allowUrlProtocols("https")
    .allowAttributes("href").onElements("a")
    .requireRelNofollowOnLinks()
```

or write custom policies to do things like changing `h1`s to `div`s with a certain class:

```
new HtmlPolicyBuilder()
    .allowElements("h1", "p")
    .allowElements(
        new ElementPolicy() {
          public String apply(String elementName, List<String> attrs) {
            attrs.add("class");
            attrs.add("header-" + elementName);
            return "div";
          }
        }, "h1"))
```

Comment: This library makes a good first impression: Well documented and a clean API.

Comment: I use this library but it removes embedded iframes as well. Is there any way to allow adding iframes, I have genuine use cases like adding embedding a youtube video or slideshare presentation. How could I allow such embedded iframes ?

Comment: @usero1, Yes, you can `allowElements("iframe")`.

Comment: Thanks so much  Mike! but the input html is like : *`<div class="embeddedContent" data-resizetype="noresize" data-align="none" data-oembed="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fC5N2EPCesk"><iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/fC5N2EPCesk?wmode=transparent&amp;jqoemcache=paWu1" width="425" height="349" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe></div>`* & in the sanitized output I get all the attributes stripped out. How do I prevent the attributes from being stripped out?  Btw Is it safe to allow iframes as such with all these attributes ?

Comment: The sanitized output I get for above input is : *`<div><iframe></iframe></div>`* which is of no use.. Thanks!

Comment: @user01, You probably have to allow the `src` attribute with a value that you approve.  See the documentation for the HTML policy builder class.

Answer (score 3):

The HTML Parser **JSoup** also supports sanitisation by policy: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer

Answer (score 2):

Apart from JTidy you can also take a look at:
[Nekohtml](http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/)
[TagSoup](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/)
[Getting text in HTmL document](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing.text.html/GetText.html)

Answer (score 1):

http://roberto.open-lab.com/2009/11/05/a-java-html-sanitizer-also-against-xss/